# Problema con Apache 2.4, Tomcat 7 y jk_mod

Tags: apache, tomcat, struts

Tengo un servidor con la siguiente configuración:
Apache 2.4.29 (64bits) + mod_jk 1.2.42 +
Tomcat 7.0.82 (con una aplicación struts)

El problema está en que aunque funciona bien la conexión entre el Apache y el Tomcat, cuando se realiza el submit de un formulario, no llegan los datos al servidor de Tomcat.
 La aplicación de struts devuelve error de campos requeridos.
Es como si la petición POST no llevase los valores del formulario.
El resto de la aplicación web funciona perfectamente, y los logs no muestran ningún warning ni ningún error.
Y si paro el Apache y accedo directamente al Tomcat, todo funciona bien. ¿Alguna idea?

**httpd.conf:**

```
<IfModule jk_module>
JkWorkersFile "E:\platj2ee\Apache24\conf\workers.properties"
JkLogFile "E:\platafj2ee\Apache24\logs\mod_jk.log"
JkLogLevel debug
JkOptions +ForwardSSLCertChain
</IfModule>


JkMount /* rrr
```

**workers.properties:**

```
worker.list=rrr
worker.cta.port=8009
worker.cta.host=localhost
worker.cta.type=ajp13
```

**server.xml:**

```
<!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
<Connector port="8009" 
           enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" protocol="AJP/1.3" connectionTimeout="60000"
            maxPostSize="0" URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema estaba con la configuración del AJP 1.3 que arrastraba de un Tomcat 5.5
 (Por lo tanto, falla tanto con mod_jk como con el mod_proxy_ajp.)
El server.xml tenía el parámetro MaxPostSize="0":

```
<!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
<Connector port="8009" 
           enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" protocol="AJP/1.3" connectionTimeout="60000"
            maxPostSize="0" URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
```

En la documentación del Tomcat 5.5 indicaban que para deshabilitar el máximo de bytes por petición POST, el valor debía ser 0 o menor que 0.
Bien, en la documentación de Tomcat 7, para deshabilitar maxPostSize, **el valor debe ser menor que 0**.

Por si alguien se encuentra en este problema, también debería revisar los valores de timeout.

Answer (score 0):

La configuracion tiene un error, si la lista de workers es rrr, no puedes tener worker.cta, debes tener worker.rrr